# TypeError: apply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I try to create a new column with a function that is based on values in another column, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-491e832a7dac> in <module>()
  4     return 'Other'
  5 
----> 6 df['PriceCatColumn'] = df.apply(PriceCat, axis=1)

TypeError: apply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

This is the code:

```
def PriceCat (row):
if row['Median ASP'] <= 50:
    return 'Category 1'
return 'Other'

df['PriceCatColumn'] = df.apply(PriceCat, axis=1)
```

What am I doing wrong, exactly? I researched solutions to this issue, but that didn't seem to lead to the answers I needed.

Answer (score 3):

## Alternatives:

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) instead if there are only 2 possible categories.

**Example**:

```
>>> df
   Median ASP
0           1
1           2
2          51
3          52
4           5

df['PriceCatColumn'] = np.where(df['Median ASP'] <= 50, 'Category 1', 'Other')

>>> df
   Median ASP PriceCatColumn
0           1     Category 1
1           2     Category 1
2          51          Other
3          52          Other
4           5     Category 1
```

If there are more categories, use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). For instance:

```
conds = [df['Median ASP'] <=3, df['Median ASP'] <=50]

choices = ['Category 1', 'Category 2']

df['PriceCatColumn'] = np.select(conds, choices, default='Other')

>>> df
   Median ASP PriceCatColumn
0           1     Category 1
1           2     Category 1
2          51          Other
3          52          Other
4           5     Category 2
```

## Your code:

That being said, your code *does* seem to work, albeit not quite as efficiently as it works with `np` methods:

```
def PriceCat (row):
    if row['Median ASP'] <= 50:
        return 'Category 1'
    return 'Other'

df['PriceCatColumn'] = df.apply(PriceCat, axis=1)

>>> df
   Median ASP PriceCatColumn
0           1     Category 1
1           2     Category 1
2          51          Other
3          52          Other
4           5     Category 1
```

Answer (score 1):

PriceCat  should take in a value, not a dataframe.

```
def PriceCat(x):
    if x <= 50:
        return 'Category 1'
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

`df['PriceCatColumn'] = df['Median ASP'].apply(PriceCat)`

> ```
>          X Median ASP PriceCatColumn
>      0    1   10  Category 1
>      1    2   20  Category 1
>      2    3   30  Category 1
>      3    4   40  Category 1
>      4    5   50  Category 1
>      5    6   60  Other
>      6    7   70  Other
>      7    8   80  Other
>      8    9   90  Other
>      9    10  100 Other
> ```